# Restrict the content only above footer

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have a footer that has a height of 100px and the css for the footer looks something like the following:

```
.footnote {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100px;

  position: fixed;
  background: url('../images/coolfooter.png') bottom center;

  bottom: 40px;
  left: 30px;
 }
```

The problem is if I have too much content on my web page, the content starts overlapping with the footer.

[image]

I want to restrict the content to only appear above the footer always somehow, so that no content gets overlapped with footer.
How can this be done?

Comment: try adding `overflow:auto;` to the content division which is above the footer.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a fully functional demo with HTML/CSS on http://jsfiddle.com/ or on a test server, as we can't help you very much with just pure CSS.

Comment: clearer explanation of what is it that holds your content? did you consider using overflow to turn on scrolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried z-index? As others have said it's a bit hard to say without looking at the html. I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer.

Comment: @hypnotoad: yes, z-index can be used. Giving footer a higher z-index can be very useful, but for the current problem we want to use a technical solution, which is available, like **overflow:scroll** etc

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to make sure that either the content has a bottom margin greater than or equal to the height of the footer, or (if the content is in a container of some sort) that it's container has a bottom padding equal to or greater than the height of the footer.

Here's a fairly popular reference site for doing this so-called "sticky footer": http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Adding `overflow:auto` to `div.content` should be sufficient.**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.header
    {
      top:0px;
      height:100px;
      max-height:120px;
      min-height:100px;
    }
    div.content
    {
      height:600px;
      max-height:750px;
      overflow:auto;
    }
    div.footer
    {
      height:100px;
      max-height:120px;
      min-height:100px;
      clear:both;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="header"></div
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```